# Why is sift.compute() slower on MSER keypoints than on SIFT keypoints

Tags: python, performance, opencv, sift, mser

Testing the performance of the sift extractor from openCV on a 1080x1080 image resulted in some unexpected results:

```
img = cv.imread("myImage.jpg", 0)  # gray
mser = cv.MSER_create()
sift = cv.SIFT_create()

kp = sift.detect(img)   # len(kp) == 5804
des = sift.compute(img, kp)  # time: 0.22s

kp = mser.detect(img)   # len(kp) == 2511
des = sift.compute(img, kp)  # time: 1.62s
```

Why is `sift.compute()` slower on MSER detected keypoints, compared to SIFT detected keypoints? Notice that MSER detects less keypoints than SIFT.

Comment: is the difference of gaussian scale space computed only once or twice when using detect + compute? Maybe sift descriptor is using the precomputed information, while in mser there is no precomputed information so during description that part has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

I've plotted the keypoints which makes clear that the MSER keypoints cover a larger area than the SIFT keypoints. This could be an explanation why it is slower.

**MSER:**

[image: sift]

**SIFT:**

[image: mser]